# Multiple text files analysis in a zip

Tags: python

It is a program `printzip.py`, which will print the contains of a zip file. Suppose, Zip contains multiple text files, so it will print the name of the text files. I am okay with it.

```
import zipfile
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('Desktop.zip', 'r')
print (zf.namelist())
```

> Output :- test1.txt, test2.txt

But, my question is, how can I take this text files for further analysis. 
Like, I want to count the line, words, characters of those text files (I can perform those operations).

But, my question is how to take this output as variable for input of further work. As we don't know the name of text files. It may be single or multiples.

As an example, I want to take test1.txt and test2.txt as an input for future operations.

Also, we did not know that zip file contains those two text files before running the `printzip.py` program. Is there any library for this multiprocessing work? Thanks.

Comment: *Is there any library for this multiprocessing work?* maybe multiprocessing? https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: There is one, ZeroMQ, But I don't have working experience with it.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you simply wish to read each contained file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zf.namelist()` returns a Python list of the names of the files in the archive. You can use a `for` loop to get each name from that list and in the loop use `zf.read()` to get the bytes of each file. For example, this will print the name list, and then the name & uncompressed size of each file in the archive.

```python
import zipfile
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('Desktop.zip', 'r')
fnames = zf.namelist()
print(fnames)
for fname in fnames:
    data = zf.read(fname)
    print(fname, len(data))
    #... do other text processing here

zf.close()
```

Comment: How does Python directly open the text file in the zip?

Comment: @ytpillai: `zf.read` isn't the standard Python `file.read` method - it's a method of the `ZipFile` class. You can see the relevant source code [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/zipfile.py).